# debian/ubuntu: Prevent UI prompting in command-line apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg, dialog

So, in order to prevent console-UI (newt, snack, dialog) prompts during the dpkg post-install, you have to do something like:

```
debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password password'
debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password verify_password'
apt-get -y install mysql-server
```

- Is there a rule for this?
- How do we discover the prompt names/descriptors for other packages that invoke the console UI in order to prevent them?
- Would we likely have to dig through the source-code to figure out how the prompts are invoked?
- Is there a simple way to just choose all defaults (effectively clicking on whatever the default button would be and/or taking the correct text/options)?

Thanks.

NOTE

It looks like setting this variable is the solution for taking the defaults:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

Comment: If it is, please add it as an answer and accept it :)

Comment: @Daniel There are four separate questions and I just noted the answer to the least of them.

Answer (score 2):

This will reconfigure your package with default parameters:

`DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg-reconfigure [package name]`

This will display parameters you set when installing a package:

`debconf-show [package name]`

This will output parameters you set when installing a package, formatted to be loaded in `debconf-set-selections`:

`debconf-get-selections | grep '^[package name]'`

To my knowledge, you can't display parameters for packages you didn't install; and you can't display default parameters without first re-configuring your package using the `noninteractive` option. You may want to use containers for testing purpose.